# Customize chatter component: Is it possible to hide the share message in chatter?

Tags: visualforce, chatter

is it possible to hide in the chatter component messaging area found in the following:

[image]

I've tried the following:

- use the onComplete Attribute to trigger JS. But i can't manage to query the box area. the component is inside another iframe

Is hiding it with css the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup -> Create -> Global Actions -> Publisher Layouts

Comment: Once i create a layout how do i change the chatter layout?

Comment: Global publisher layout is set automatically to all objects with Feed Tracking on  if you want to change it to a specific layout go to Edit layout and You can override the global publisher layout.